# Replacing Timer text with result of DB calculation when Timer hits 00:00:00

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, razor

I have a jQuery Countdown Timer that I am using, and I need to be able to access my Database and perform some calculations and then return the result:

```
$('#expireMessage').countdown({until: shortly,
    expiryText: '<div class="over">It\'s all over</div>'});

$('#expireMessageStart').click(function() {
    shortly = new Date();
    shortly.setSeconds(shortly.getSeconds() + 5.5);
    $('#expireMessage').countdown('change', {until: shortly});
});
```

Now, the above code just displays a countdown timer, and counts down. And when it hits

> 00:00:00

it displays a message "It's all over".

But what I need it to do is display a different message depending on the result of the DB calculations.

The DB work I can do, but I'm not sure how to go about retrieving that info from the database when using jQuery. I'd really appreciate your help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up something on the server side to talk to the database for you, then return the result in JSON format. What that something is depends on what your server-side code is written in. Are you using PHP? Java? ASP.NET?

I work primarily in ASP.NET, so one way I might tackle this is adding a `WebMethod` to my page that executes a database query, builds the message, serializes it to JSON, and returns it to the client.

In your JavaScript, you'll want to execute either an `XMLHttpRequest` (if you're using regular JavaScript) or a jQuery AJAX request.

Here's a very simple example of what a jQuery AJAX call might look like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://mysite.com/getmymessage',
  success: function( data ) {
      // Here's where you'd update your countdown display, but I'm just writing to the console
      console.log( 'The server says: ' + data.myDbResult );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, @Josh. Am I looking for something like Callback feature in jQuery? Is that the part that lets me call a function in server-side code file?

Comment: The JavaScript part is an AJAX request. A callback is something different, but related. You _will_ use a callback with an AJAX request, but they are not the same thing. A callback is a function that you give to another function. In this case, you'll write your AJAX function, then give it a callback that will get executed when the message comes back from the server/DB.